# How to not print meta table log in spring-batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, logback, spring-jdbc

logback.xml

```
<logger name="org.springframework.batch" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="INFO"/>
```

log

> 2022.02.23 14:25:50 jdbc.sqltiming SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID FROM BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE WHERE JOB_NAME="testJob"
>
> 2022.02.23 14:25:50 jdbc.sqltiming INSERT INTO testTable (a, b, c) VALUES (11, 22, 33)

Spring-batch automatically logs to database.
but, I don't need batch meta table log. Is it possible to hide automatically executed batch query?
thanks

Comment: Did you try `level="OFF"`?

Comment: I need the sql log. I just want to disable the meta table log output. thanks

Comment: extends ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter